# Using ObjectID with jwt.sign() and verify()

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bson

Upon logging in to my system, I run the MongoDB `_id` of the logged in user through the [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)'s `sign` method. It returns to me a hash, which I then put into the session headers of every subsequent request that the client makes to my server.

I now want to decode the session and recover the string `_id` from the headers, so I run it against the jsonwebtoken's `verify` method. I am not doing this for authentication (that's already handled by looking the session up in a DB). I'm recovering the `_id` so I can log the user's activities in a separate collection. I run the `verify` function through a middleware and save the decoded result in `req.decoded`.

However, when I log `req.decoded`, it is a BSON object, rather than a string:

```
{ _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
  id:
   { type: 'Buffer',
     data: [ 89, 128, 145, 134, 118, 9, 216, 20, 175, 174, 247, 33 ] },
  iat: 1501903389,
  exp: 1501989789 }
```

How can I recover the `_id` value from this object, such that I can look for this record again in my collections?

#### What I've tried

I've tried the following, without success:

- `model.find(req.decoded).then()` gives me this error:

  Error: object [contents of req.decoded here] is not a valid ObjectId
- `model.find({_id: req.decoded})` gives me this error:

  { CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value [contents of req.decoded here]  at path "_id" for model [model here]
- `req.decoded.toString()` logs [object Object]
- `JSON.stringify(req.decoded)` just turns the BSON into a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This of course is subjective to how you actually supply the data to `.sign()` in the first place, being the difference of simply supplying the "object" of `ObjectID` **or** by supplying the value instead.

This is actually covered in the [general usage for `.sign()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback) as :

> If payload is not a buffer or a string, it will be coerced into a string using JSON.stringify.

So in a nutshell that version is going to "stringify" the Object form an require some "digging". In your form the decoded object then has properies of `id` with a sub-property of `data` which contains an array of bytes than can be converted into a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). So that's what you do:

```
  let newId = Buffer.from(req.decoded.id.data).toString('hex');
```

And `newId` would then be a "string" represented by the `'hex'` encoded values of the bytes. This of course would be translated by mongoose into an `ObjectId` when issued in any "query" or "update" as matching the schema for `_id`.

Of course the "alternative" would be simply to `.sign()` using the `.toString()` value from the `ObjectId` in the first place. Then the result of [`.verify()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback) would simply the be "hex string" that as supplied, rather than the `JSON.stringify` result on the `ObjectID` itself.

To demonstrate with a listing:

```
const bson = require('bson'),
      jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// Stored ObjectID
console.log("Round 1");
(function() {
  let id = new bson.ObjectID();
  console.log("Created: %s", id);

  let token = jwt.sign(id,'shhh');                // Supply value as ObjectID
  let decoded = jwt.verify(token,'shhh');

  console.log("Interim");
  console.log(decoded);

  let newId = Buffer.from(decoded.id.data).toString('hex');
  console.log("Decoded: %s", newId);
})();

console.log("\nRound 2");
// Stored String value
(function() {

  let id = new bson.ObjectID();
  console.log("Created: %s", id);

  let token = jwt.sign(id.toString(), 'shhh');    // Supply value as string
  let decoded = jwt.verify(token,'shhh');

  console.log("Decoded: %s", decoded);

})();
```

Gives the output, showing the input values and decoded values:

```
Round 1
Created: 59857328090c497ce787d087
Interim
{ _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
  id:
   { type: 'Buffer',
     data: [ 89, 133, 115, 40, 9, 12, 73, 124, 231, 135, 208, 135 ] },
  iat: 1501917992 }
Decoded: 59857328090c497ce787d087

Round 2
Created: 59857328090c497ce787d088
Decoded: 59857328090c497ce787d088
```

And demonstrates both forms of usage for supplying the value to `.sign()` and what comes out from the subsequent `.verify()` calls.